# Python negate boolean function

Tags: python, standard-library

A python boolean function can easily be negated with lambda functions, but it's a bit verbose and hard to read for something so basic, for example:

```
def is_even(n):
    return n % 2 == 0

odds_under_50 = filter(lambda x: not is_even(x), range(50))
```

I'm wondering if there is a function to do this in the standard library, which might look like:

```
odds_under_50 = filter(negate(is_even), range(50))
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no *builtin* function, but you can easily define your own higher order function for that...

Comment: Not to my knowledge; in this case I would just go with a list comprehension: `[xi for xi in range(50) if not is_even(xi)]`

Comment: @Cleb: not that in Python-3.x `filter` and this list comprehension are not equivalent since `filter` is lazy: you can `filter` an infinite generator whereas you cannot do that with list comprehension.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: What exactly would be the differences in practical terms? Might be tricky to discuss in the comments but I currently don't see the difference. When I read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), I don't spot the difference either (apart from list vs. iterator).

Comment: if you `import itertools` and then do `[xi for xi in itertools.repeat(1) if not is_even(xi)]` this will run out of memory. `filter` will evaluate lazily and thus not consume CPU/memory at all.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Ok, thanks for the explanation. Then I of course fully agree.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As far as I know there is no *builtin* function for that, or a popular library that does that.

Nevertheless, you can easily write one yourself:

```
from functools import wraps

def negate(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def g(*args,**kwargs):
        return not f(*args,**kwargs)
    g.__name__ = f'negate({f.__name__})'
    return g
```

You can then use:

```
odds_under_50 = filter(negate(is_even), range(50))
```

The `negate` function works for an arbitrary amount of parameters of the given function: if you would have defined `is_dividable(x,n=2)`. Then `negate(is_dividable)` is a function with two arguments (one optional) that would also accept these parameters.

Comment: Here it's worth noting that the negated function will have the same docstring and name as the original function, which may not be a good idea.

Comment: What is the use of `@wraps` here?

Comment: @cs95: ensure that the parameter data is the same as `f`, otherwise it is just `*args` and `**kwargs`.

Comment: @cs95: probably we can use `g.__name__ = f'negate({f.__name__})'` and thus retain the parameter data *and* change the name of the function to `negate(f)`, that would make it better since then we get for help `negate(f)(a, b)` if `f` has parameters `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 6):

In case of `filter` you can use `ifilterfalse` (or `filterfalse` in Python 3.x) from `itertools`.

Comment: That does not really answers the question.

Comment: It's useful! Thank you! Python 3 docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse

Answer (score 3):

You can create a decorator:

```
def negate(function):
    def new_function(*args, **kwargs):
       return not function(*args, **kwargs)
    return new_function


def is_even(x):
    return x % 2 == 0

print is_even(1)
print is_even(2)

is_odd = negate(is_even)
print is_odd(1)
print is_odd(2)
```

This decorator can also be used with @negate.

```
@negate
def is_odd(x):
    return x % 2 == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

With `funcy`'s or [`toolz`'s](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=compose#toolz.functoolz.compose) `compose` function you can negate the function like that:

```py
import operator

import funcy

is_odd = funcy.compose(operator.not_, is_even)
```

If you want to make it more readable:

```py
def negate(func):
    return funcy.compose(operator.not_, func)

is_odd = negate(is_even)

# or without creating the function directly
print(negate(is_even)(5))
```

The [funcy library has a lot of other useful functions for functional programming](https://funcy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheatsheet.html).